# module differential connectivity (MDC) analysis

Tags: r, wgcna

In [this paper](https://www.cell.com/neuron/pdf/S0896-6273(16)30074-5.pdf) I am citing the lines below:

> Intra-modular connectivity of resilient and susceptible network modules was compared to that of corresponding genes in control mice to identify gain, loss, or no change.Pie charts (lower panel) summarize module differential connectivity (MDC) analysis. Proportionally, very few resilient modules had significant MDC compared to more than half of all susceptible modules, which predominantly showed gain of connectivity
>
> A module differential connectivity (MDC) metric quantified differences in coexpression networks to identify phenotype-specific modules
> (Zhang et al., 2013)

Need to clarify whether this "module differential connectivity (MDC)" analysis is a part of WGCNA or its an independent analysis. Because if I do a search for `module differential connectivity(MDC)analysis` the result I get is this `DGCA: Differential Gene Correlation Analysis'. But no where in the paper they have mentioned "DGCA" library in the citation.

It would be helpful if i get some suggestion regarding this analysis.

This is the paper:

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3677161/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Answer from @devon-ryan, converted from comments:*

They described how they did it in that paper, there's just not a tool for it. It's not part of anything. They describe the algorithm, maybe DGCA implemented it, maybe not, but they don't mention using it. WGCNA was obviously used to define the modules, though.